# way to interrupt console.log from calling & replace it with another function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, eval

im looking for a way to interrupt console.log in React and replace it with another functionality while using `eval()`

planning to build a codepen alternative but it should be run functionality like display to a div or something while calling `console.[]`

Comment: Just monkey-patch it?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with react or strict mode.

Comment: is this possible to monkey-patch it on every different child components. So it works different on each eval() from each child components?

Comment: Wait you mean that the user code that you are `eval`ing is react components?